# Copy constructor is not called when creating and assigning to array

Tags: c++, linux, c++11

Why the Sample class copy constructor is not called in the below example when I try to initialize Sample class  `user():newObj{ {1,1,{0,0,100,100}} , {2,2, {0,0,100,100}} }`

```
#include <iostream>

struct Point
{
    int x_, y_, x1_, y1_;
    public:
    Point(int x, int y, int x1, int y1)
    {
        x_ = x;
        y_ = y;
        x1_ = x1;
        y1_ = y1;
    }
    Point(const Point &temp)
    {
        std::cout << "Point copyyyyyyyyyyyy cons called" << std::endl;
        x_ = temp.x_;
        x1_ = temp.x1_;
        y_ = temp.y_;
        y_ = temp.y1_;
    }
};
class Sample
{
    public:
    Sample(int a, int b, const Point& p):pointObj(p)
    {
        a_ = a;
        b_ = b;
        std::cout << "Sample constructor called \n" ;
    }
#if 0 
Sample(const Sample& temp):pointObj(temp.pointObj)
{
    std::cout << "coooooooooooppppppppppppy constructor called" << std::endl;
    a_ = temp.a_;
    b_ = temp.b_;
}
#endif
    private:
   Sample(const Sample&) = delete;
   Sample( volatile  const Sample&) = delete;
   Sample( volatile  Sample&) = delete;
   Sample(Sample&) = delete;
    int a_;
    int b_;
    Point pointObj;
};
class user
{
    private:
        Sample newObj[2];
        Point tempPoint{0,0,100,100};
       
    public:
        user():newObj{ {1,1,{0,0,100,100}} , {2,2, {0,0,100,100}} }
        {
            std::cout << " user constructor called" << std::endl;
        }
};
int main() {
    // Write C++ code here
    user userObj;
    return 0;
}
```

ouput:

```
Point copyyyyyyyyyyyy cons called
Sample constructor called 
Point copyyyyyyyyyyyy cons called
Sample constructor called 
 user constructor called
```

Comment: Where do you expect the copy constructor to need to be called?  q.v. [copy elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision)

Answer (score 1):

```
newObj{ ... }
```

This syntax introduces initialization of `newObj`. That's what these braces mean.

Each value inside the brace, in the case where `newObj` is an array (as is the case here) is expected to initialize each corresponding value in the array.

`{1,1,{0,0,100,100}}`

And this is the first value in this array. It, itself, is a braced initialization list. In the case where the value that gets initialized is an instance of a class, an object, the values in the initialization list get passed to the object's constructor, as the parameters to the constructor.

You were expecting a discrete `Sample` to get constructed, then copied into its corresponding array value (and failing because the copy constructor is deleted). However, nothing gets constructed, somewhere, and then copied, using the services of a copy constructor. Each value in the array gets constructed directly.

You can peel off the remaining braces, and finish out the rest of this excersize in exactly the same way.